# Import XML by matching on tag attribute content in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have an XML data file that looks like this:

```
<Sales>
    <Store Number="8" Date="2012-08-20T03:00:00">
        <Value Field="CanceledOrders" Value="65.00"/>
        <Value Field="TotalDollars" Value="13.57"/>
    </Store>
    <Store Number="10" Date="2012-08-20T03:00:00">
        <Value Field="CanceledOrders" Value="38.00"/>
        <Value Field="TotalDollars" Value="29.22"/>
    </Store>
</Sales>
```

I am scratching my head on how to extract this into a normal SQL table like this:

```
+--------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
| Number |        Date         | CanceledOrders | TotalDollars |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
|      8 | 2012-08-20T03:00:00 | 65.00          | 13.57        |
|     10 | 2012-08-20T03:00:00 | 38.00          | 29.22        |
+--------+---------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Here is what I have so far. I can't figure out how to match on XML attribute content value.
I would like to match on the /Sales/Store/Value/@Field contents and return the value from /Sales/Store/Value/@Value.

```
DECLARE @X AS xml

SET @X = '<Sales>
  <Store Number="8" Date="2012-08-20T03:00:00">
    <Value Field="CanceledOrders" Value="65.00" />
    <Value Field="TotalDollars" Value="13.57" />
  </Store>
  <Store Number="10" Date="2012-08-20T03:00:00">
    <Value Field="CanceledOrders" Value="38.00" />
    <Value Field="TotalDollars" Value="29.22" />
  </Store>
</Sales>'

-- This is my start but it obviously doesn't return what I need.
SELECT Y.ID.value('(@Number)[1]', 'int') AS Number,
       Y.ID.value('(@Date)[1]', 'datetime') AS [Date],
       Y.ID.value('(Value/@Field)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS "Field",
       Y.ID.value('(Value/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS "Value"
FROM   @X.nodes('/Sales/Store') AS Y(ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
   Y.ID.value('(@Number)[1]', 'int') AS Number,
   Y.ID.value('(@Date)[1]', 'datetime') AS [Date],
   CancelledOrders = Y.ID.value('(Value[@Field="CanceledOrders"]/@Value)[1]', 'decimal(18,4)'),
   TotalDollars = Y.ID.value('(Value[@Field="TotalDollars"]/@Value)[1]', 'decimal(18,4)')
FROM   
   @input.nodes('/Sales/Store') AS Y(ID)
```